# Distance betwen points based on hydrological net using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, point, distance

I need calculate the distance between all points but not linear distance. I need to calculate the distance based on the hydrological net. I have one point layer and one shape that belong to the hydrological net.

I am using ArcGIS full version.

What tool can I use?

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: im using ArcGIS full version.

Answer (score -1):

For proprietary software, Esri's Network Analyst will work. For open source, you can use GRASS through QGIS or PG Routing (Postgis).

I really like the GRASS approach and there is pretty good documentation available [here](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Vector_network_analysis). You will need to create a mapset in GRASS, import your network and points into your mapset, set up your network (v.net), and then calculate distances (v.net.distance). Once complete, just load the layers into QGIS and save into your preferred spatial format.

Comment: network analysis isnt a good choice, cause i have arround 1000 points and i will make a distance matrix and i will have make 1000 times the methodology

Comment: A well crafted PostGIS/pgRouting  query could handle that, but either way you will end up with a huge dataset.